# how to Query Firestore for a field added at a later date

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Say I want to add a new field to each record in firestore, eg. `isArchived: boolean`

However, the database is already in production! This gives the biggest problem:

> **You cannot query for documents like `where('isArchived', '!=', true)` because this will not include docs without the new field `isArchived`.**

#### strategy for adding a new field

- first update all documents in the database and add the new field
- then you can query for `where('isArchived', '!=', true)`

#### the remaining problem

When some clients did not update to the latest version of my app, they will still add documents without the new field. So the search logic of the new version will still miss documents.

#### work around for the remaining problem

also add a cloud function that checks for the missing field upon adding new records.

but then the new problem is:

- this will cost me double the money for every record write
- it's difficult to know when I can deprecate this cloud function

#### advice requested

I feel there must be a better way to add new fields to a record at a later date. (With SQL you can migrate and set a default value?)

Can anyone give me a better solution than the very bad workaround I'm currently employing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore doesn't have migrations like many SQL databases, so there's no path like that you can take.

The best way to handle document versioning like this is to have shipped all code that reads and write document to observe a document version field in each document.  You would use this version to determine which individual documents have and have not been migrated.  Of course, if you don't have a document version field, adding one introduces the same problem that you're describing here.

The only viable workaround is to use a [Cloud Functions Firestore trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore) to get a callback that runs in Google Cloud whenever a document is added to the database, and look at the fields in the document to determine if and how it needs to change.  So, if a client fails to write an `isArchived` field, the function can simply re-write the document to add it.  After you've deployed this function and it's working correctly, you can run the code to migrate all the existing documents that don't have this field.

If you do version your documents, migrations becomes easier in the future, because now you have a clear value to filter on for any future triggers or code that needs to understand what is supposed to be in each document.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice!
Do you think it will in the future ever be possible to query documents that have `void` for a given field? (in other words, query for eg. `where('newField', '==', void 0)` to get docs that don't have that field)

Comment: No, void is not a valid field value.

Comment: Do you think there will be a way in the future to query docs that are missing a specified field? Regardless of how such a syntax would look. : )